# Event Driven Thread

Tags: java, synchronization

I have often come across this snippet :

```
{

 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
   {
   public void run() {
     new tester();  // class name
   }
 });

}
```

I know why are we using this,but cannot understand how it is going.I mean i dont understand this snippet.

(We are initializing object under run method,,,why?? )

Please explain this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that bit of code you're creating a `Inner Class` that implements `Runnable`, that instance will be enqueued in the AWT processing task dispatcher for later processing in a thread. Quoting the documentation, `invokeLater` ...

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed
>   asynchronously on the AWT event
>   dispatching thread. This will happen
>   after all pending AWT events have been
>   processed.

So at some point, the AWT dispatcher will decide to run that instance of Runable in a thread. That will provoke the execution of the method `run` and therefore the execution of the statement `new tester();`, which simply create an instance of the class `tester`.

To your specific question ...

> We are initializing object under run
>   method,,,why??

It really doesn't seem right to just create a class in the `run` method, unless the constructor is doing lots of things which is actually a bad practice.

It'be much more intuitive to do something like :

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
   {
   public void run() {
     Tester t = new Tester();
     t.doSomeStuff();
   }
 });
```

Comment: I would'nt say "is a Thread that will be enqueued in the AWT processing task dispatcher". What is enqueued are not threads at all. Just Runnable object, whose run methods are then executed by the Event Dispatch Thread (AWT thread).

Comment: @barjak nice point (+1). I do agree with you, threads runs object and Runable instances are enqueued. I'll change that wording.

Comment: @Suhail Gupta see the new edition to see if you can understand it. If you don't please let me know exactly what bit is confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical way of injecting some code in a dedicated thread. AWT is not thread-safe (as all UI toolkits are), and thus all the code that deals with AWT must be executed in a spêcial thread, the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

To do so, AWT has a queue of "piece of code" to be called in the EDT : the [EventQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html). The EDT is just a loop that dequeues the next "piece of code" to execute, and runs it. These "pieces of code" are actually just `Runnable` instances. These can be UI events (mouse, keyboard) or code that you, as a developper give to him.

Calling `invokeLater` just tells the EDT to enqueue a `Runnable` instance in its `EventQueue`. The runnable you enqueued will be executed (or more precisely its `run` method will be executed) in the EDT, when it will be its turn.

This way of passing code from one thread to another is very common and useful : it's a great way of serializing pieces of code that come from different threads. The only thing that needs to be thread-safe is the queue itself.