# Method in constructor?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have often come across this snippet :

General form of invokeLater is - static void invokeLater(Runnable *obj*)

But i have often come across these types of codes:

```
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     new tester();
   }
 });
```

}

or-----(example of another type)

```
{
   clean.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     cleanActionPerformed(ae);
   }
 });
```

}

Now what is this? 
There is method in the constructor!! I am unable to understand the way of writing these snippets.
Explain very clearly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event Driven Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339025/event-driven-thread)

Comment: This is similar to your other question, [How does this method work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335161/how-does-this-method-work), as well as your question that Bombe pointed out. When an answer doesn't make sense, leave a comment asking for clarification; don't keep posting the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see are anonymous inner classes. They are one-shot classes that you won't use anywhere else.

Take a look at this piece:

```
clean.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     cleanActionPerformed(ae);
   }
 });
```

`addActionListener` is expecting an implementation of an [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), which is an interface.

Now, you could write a whole new class that implements it and then put an instance of it as an argument of `addActionListener`, but this way is faster to write (and a bit harder to read) if you won't use such a class anywhere else.

The same effect could have been achieved with this:

```
class SomeActionListener implements ActionListener {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
       cleanActionPerformed(ae);
   }
}

...

clean.addActionListener(new SomeActionListener());
```

Comment: in this clean.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     cleanActionPerformed(ae);
   }
 });
what does new ActionListener() denote??

Answer (score 3):

They are called anonymous classes, you can read up on them at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Answer (score 2):

They're anonymous classes.

You *could* write them as a class in their own file,instantiate it, and pass it as the argument... but for one-off use that is the easier way to do it.

(As Matt notes in a comment below, "easier" in that you don't have to create the files and write out the classes, etc)

Comment: "easier" as in amount of code you have to write; the effects at runtime are identical

Answer (score 0):

Its called [anonymous Inner class](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/anonymous_innerclassestutorial.shtml), where object is declared and initialized at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

These are just anonymous classes or a local class without a name. Anonymous classes are usually used when you will only reference a class once.

Instead of doing `addListener(this)` and having your class implement some interface.